# How To Keep Soft Keyboard On Until User Press On "Return" On Xamarin Forms's Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am currently developing a live chat app, and I faced a problem where everytime send button is clicked, the soft keyboard being turned off. I made some custom rendering on the entry to keep the keyboard on using the following code:

```
Control.ShouldEndEditing = (UITextField textField) =>
{
    return !chatEntryView.Focus();
};
```

However this will keeps the keyboard on forever. I would like to close the keyboard whenever use press on "Return" only. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you facing the same issue in android aswell or is it only in iOS

Comment: I never tried android yet, but now i am developing ios so should the focus is on ios only

Comment: So all you want is the keyboard only disappear on return key

Comment: Yeah exactly, i want to remain the keyboard on until user press on Return only to close it